# Como puedo buscar dentro de un array de objetos?

Tags: java

necesito buscar dentro de un array de objetos y estoy teniendo muchos problemas por que no es simplemente buscar dentro de un array, es buscar dentro del array y luego buscar dentro del objeto para ver que objeto es.

```
 public class arrayMultimedia {

 int numOB = 10;
 Multimedia[] miLista = new Multimedia[numOB];


 public arrayMultimedia( int maxArg) {
    
   
     this.numOB = maxArg; 
    
   
 }

   ola.miLista[0] = new Multimedia("hola", "soyun", "array", 0, 0);


 if(Arrays.asList(miLista).contains() == true) {
          
          System.out.println(miLista[0]);
          
      }else {
          
          System.out.println("nulllll");
          
      }
```

esto es lo que probado, pero no funciona porque dentro del array no hay strings ni nada parecido, si no un objeto con sus atributos(string int...)

Comment: en qué versión de Java? es relevante?

Comment: la ultima version.

Comment: te refieres a la 16? o a la beta del 17?

Comment: La explicación que das es muy poco clara y el código que publicas en la pregunta ni siguiera compila... tiene errores de sintaxis y hay identificadores, como `ola` que no están definidos. Te recomiendo leer [ask] e incluir un [mcve] en tu pregunta.